# HTML5 Offline Storage on iPad and iPhone BUG

Tags: iphone, ipad, html, manifest

I created a manifest file with 1000 items. Safari, Mozilla browsers are saving the files offline successfully and even Android saves the files correctly offline.

On iPad and iPhone when I am trying to save more than 300 items in some point the applicationCache returns "error". When I am trying to save less (e.x.: 200) it saves the files correctly and the applicationCache returns "cached".

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you file a bug report yet?

Comment: I have a similar issue on ipad. Always get "error" event from the applicationCache after the last "progress" event. Cache contains only ~30 items. Works fine on iphone 2,3 and 4. Still happens if the CACHE section is empty.

Comment: the cache is so random, hard to control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to specs, 
http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

there is no limit, but

'A mostly arbitrary limit of five megabytes per origin is recommended. Implementation feedback is welcome and will be used to update this suggestion in the future.'

Answer (score 2):

in iOS 3, max size is 5M, in iOS 4.2 beta3, the browser will ask for the permission (to increase the max size of applicationCache) when downloaded files size is bigger than 5M.